# Powershell comparing values / then checking the validity

Tags: powershell

I have been trying numerous functions in Powershell including Comparison Object, for each function but with no success.

This is what I want to do.

I have two files named as File 1 and File 2. Within File 1, I have a line like this.

In File 2, I have this.

So I want to compare the value of ContractGroups from File 1 to the value of ContractGroups in file 2. If matched, I want to add an outcome to the file.

The difficulty I am having is that I can set up a variable to get the content for matching. But when comparing, I want to only take into account of ContractGroups for a match. So as soon as file 2 is scanned, then I want to see if the value of ContractGroups matches to file 1.

I have tried this.

```
$file1 = Get-Content "C:\Users\Altunokc\Desktop\Guardian\NotUsed\20200513 Environment parameters\EnvironmentParameters_ICE_EU_PROD.xml" 
$file2 = Get-Content "C:\Users\Altunokc\Desktop\inetpub\wwwroot\EU\Guardian\Website\appSettings.config"
$pattern = $file1| %{$_ -MATCH   '.Name="ContractGroups" Value'}


$result = "C:\Users\Altunokc\Desktop\Differentdd.txt"

$file1 | foreach { $pattern = $file2 -match $_

        if ( $match ) { $match | Out-File -Force $result -Append }
       
      }
```

and this way

```
if(Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $(Get-Content $file2 )   -DifferenceObject $(Get-Content $file1 ) | %{$_ -MATCH   '.Name="ContractGroups" Value'}  -SimpleMatch|
Out-File  -FilePath C:\Users\Altunokc\Desktop\Different.txt)

 {"match"}
Else  {"No "}
```

No luck.

I think for comparison, I just need to find a way of scanning the line that contains Name="ContractGroups" Value from file 1 and then reading its value (CC) and then scanning file 2 to first see if has a line matches Name="ContractGroups" Value and if yes, and then does the value of it is the same (CC) as file one? If yes, then just write that "Matched" to a blank file.

It would be helpful if you shed light on this. Sorry as I am new on PS.

Comment: your text mentions "Within File 1, I have a line like this.` and a similar statement for the 2nd file ... but there is no sample of either file. a sample of the data to work with would make this much less abstract. [*grin*]

Comment: Not sure what you mean.

Comment: you say `I have two files named as File 1 and File 2. Within File 1, I have a line like this.` ... but you have no `this` listed.